# Which shopify apps can be used with Hydrogen?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-hydrogen

I'm pulling out my hair over this, but I cannot seem to find a solid answer over which shopify apps can I use for a new storefront built on Hydrogen 2.0 and Shopify Plus

I can see this page which seems to indicate it is possible "to extend hydrogen build with apps": https://apps.shopify.com/collections/apps-to-extend-hydrogen-build

But I can see no indication on how would I use an app like this (which is created by shopify): https://apps.shopify.com/search-and-discovery

It's fine if the app only provides admin functionality and I need to access the data it creates through APIs (like related/complementary products), but I cannot find any documentation on if it is possible or not.

And when searching for Apps, is it possible to determine (from the "apps store") if said app is usable with hydrogen or is it only for liquid themes?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Hydrogen is nothing but a front-end for Shopify. Anything you're doing with Hydrogen has an analog with the standard theme template system. If an App helps the non-Hydrogen Shopify store front, there is nothing stopping you from using the same App. Why are you pulling out your hair?

Comment: Thanks, why I was pulling my hair out is that the apps not depending on frontend was not clear at all from high-level documentation for me and I needed to make a decision without having time to experiment with it.

Comment: That's not really the whole story though - the overwhelming majority of Shopify apps won't work with Hydrogen as they're designed to generate Liquid. There's a list of supported apps here: https://apps.shopify.com/collections/apps-to-extend-hydrogen-build (although there may be more).

Comment: Vague questions get answers that seem vague sure. If an App just manipulates a theme and inserts custom liquid, then sure, you would not use it with Hydrogen. That is not a hair ripper, that is just common sense in analyzing an App you might want to use, but can't for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

All Shopify apps that support the API will work with Hydrogen, like: Back in Stock Alert, Yotpo Product Review,...You can use many other 3rd party services (If these services support via API) like: Algolia Search, Tawk.to (Chat service), SendGrid (for newsletter subscribe), etc..

Comment: "All Shopify apps that support the API will work with Hydrogen" - what do you mean by "apps that support the API"? Where is this support indicated?

Comment: Since Hydrogen will fetch data via the API, the app needs to be able to push the API. Currently, most Shopify Apps that work with Liquid cannot push APIs because Liquid doesn't need.